# Sql Azure - Frequent timeout error

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-sql-database, connection-timeout

I am using azure sql with many quartz windows service which runs every 2 mins. I sometimes get following error

```
Message:An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner 
 exception for details.|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A 
 transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. 
 (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean 
 breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, 
 Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject 
 stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject 
 stateObj, UInt32 error) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync() at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket() at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer() at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand 
 cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, 
 TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior 
 runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
 RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& 
 task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
 RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, 
 TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) 
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
 RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String 
 method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior 
 behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
 at 
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass
 b.b__8() at 
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterc
 eptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, 
 Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed) at 
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand 
 command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at 
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavi
 or behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior 
 behavior) at 
 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCo
 mmands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) 
 ClientConnectionId:9a85a9a9-69aa-4a68-8e05-e54adf5ac318
```

Any Idea how to resolve this? We are using EF 6.1 and open context in "using" block.

Comment: Most likely Transient errors
 http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290720/azure-website-sometimes-cant-connect-to-sql-azure-database/23295389#23295389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290720/azure-website-sometimes-cant-connect-to-sql-azure-database#). While working with Azure SQL we should have logic to retry the database operation. EF 6.0 gives it out of the box